# Python check list evenness

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Is there a pythonic way to find out which number is different in evenness from others ?

E.g.:

input: `"2 4 7 8 10"` =>  output: 3 // Third number is odd, while the rest of the numbers are even

input: `"1 2 1 1"` => 2 // Second number is even, while the rest of the numbers are odd

Bellow is my approach, where `numbers` is the input as `str`:

```py
def evenness(numbers):

    bool_number = list(map(lambda i: i%2==0, map(lambda i: int(i), numbers.split(" ")))) 

    if bool_number.count(True) == 1:
        return bool_number.index(True)+1
    else:
        return bool_number.index(False)+1
```

Thanks

Comment: What would be the output for `'1 3 5 2 4 8'`?

Comment: Hi @Ch3steR, currently I do not have test cases for the same number of even and odd numbers, and also if there are more than one even/odd number in the string. But thanks for heads-up I will have to cover them also .

Comment: You can [edit] the question and add all relevant information.

Comment: So would you want all indexes that where 'off' on their evenness. For example: "2 4 7 8 9" There are more even than odd, so would you want the both indexes odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only ever have one instance of an odd/even discrepancy, you can convert all numbers to 1s (for odds) and 0s (for evens) and check for the first 1 or first 0 depending on whether you have more than one odd:

```
s     = "2 4 7 8 10"
odds  = [int(n)&1 for n in s.split()]
index = odds.index(sum(odds)==1)+1

print(index) # 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function it will return you the index of the only item that is different then the others and if there will be more then one or zero occurrence then it will return -1

```
def evenness(numbers):
    res = list(filter(lambda x: x.count(0) == len(x) -1, [[i if int(n) % 2 else 0 for i, n in enumerate(numbers.split(" "))], [i if not int(n) % 2 else 0 for i, n in enumerate(numbers.split(" "))]]))
    return -1 if len(res) != 1 else sum(res[0])
```